# How to get post which has date meta value larger than a certain date in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to use the below code to get all posts which `meta_key`   `deadline` is larger than a certain date value?

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => 'deadline',
    'meta_value'       => LARGER THAN 2016-04-19,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add the date query:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'deadline'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'the_date',
        'value' => '2016-04-19',
        'compare' => '>='
    )
),
```

Modify it for what you need, but this should work.

Comment: This is usefull only if you work with the post publish time, not for a meta.

Comment: Updated, this should help.

Comment: @wesside where does "the_date" come from?

Comment: @wesside I wonder if wordpress understands that we want to compare deadline with a date, not a deadline with a string (2016-04-19).